# How to generate an RDP file

Tags: c#, rdp

In my application I have a requirement for being able to import RDP files, store them in settings, and run them from within the app (basically RDP management functionality), but the second requirement is one that I do not know how to go about this, Basically I want to let the user create a new RDP, typing the Hostname and then that's it the rest would be done via the RDP program, but if user would like to save this, how to generate an Default RDP file for the Domain containing the server/PC/Laptop name?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

RDP Files are plain text only.

It should contains, at least :

```
full address:s:<hostname> or <IP Address>
```

Answer (score 12):

RDP Files are text files basically. The configuration values are stored in a `option:type:value` format as you can see on this page: [Supported Remote desktop RDP file settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/rdp-files).

Comment: Or this page [Supported Remote desktop RDP file settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/rdp-files)