# How to download .rdp file in AWS using Python Boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, rdp

I have few windows based EC2 instances on AWS, i am using python/ boto 3
How can i download the .rdp file for all those instances on my local machine via my script

Please suggest
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. However, you could create your own, since an RDP file simply contains text.

See: [c# - How to generate an RDP file - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39915623/how-to-generate-an-rdp-file)

You can call [`get_password_data()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.get_password_data) to retrieve the encrypted administrator password for a running Windows instance, but I don't think it is stored in the RDP file.

Comment: Right okay , any way how i can automate the process to connect to all the instances?  and have seperate connections open for each one of them  I have all the IP addresses accessible in my script.